# Raw score for GRE?

Tags: application, university, gre

I am currently completing my application for MIT, and they demand the raw scores for the GRE general and subject tests. However, on my ETS account, I only see my percentile and my scaled score. How can I see my raw score? Is there a different way than looking it up in a conversion table?

Answer (score 3):

ETS doesn't release "raw" scores—I believe what the application is asking for means to provide them with the scaled score (and percentile). (You're never told how many questions you've gotten right or wrong.) If you need to provide a true "raw" score, then you'd have to use a conversion table.